# How can i fix “this is undefined” in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined, nuxt.js

The line `this.$store.commit('disconnect');` is causing a "this is undefined" error, what can i do ?

***store/index.js :***

```
export const state = () => ({
  log: false,
  user: {token: null, id: null, username: null, email: null, created_at: null, pseudo: null}
})


export const mutations = {
  connect (state) {
    state.log = true
  },
  disconnect (state) {
    state.log = false,
    state.user.id = null,
    state.user.username = null,
    state.user.email = null,
    state.user.created_at = null,
    state.user.pseudo = null
  }
}
```

***index.vue***

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

  methods: {
    async login() {
    var self = this;

    const auth_res = axios({
      method:'post',
      url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/v2.0/auth',
      data:{
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      }
      }).then(function(res){
        this.$store.commit('disconnect');
        self.$router.push('/');
      }).catch(function (erreur) {
        console.log(erreur);
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If i delete the line of the `commit` in the `index.vue` file, it works fine, but i need to use it so how can i fix this ?

Thanks again

Comment: You say that the error is this undefined, but in the little code you pasted you use self. Paste the whole method/computer where you using it to allow people to help

Comment: I forgot to change that when i posted my question, its just a `this`. @Raffobaffo

Comment: `this` is always context dependant, show the code, just a line of code says nothing about `this`

Comment: Is `this.$store.commit('connect')` invoked in a component lifecycle method or you have it exactly in that way in your vue template? You need to provide some more context surround the invocation in `index.vue`

Comment: i added the rest of the code :) @arieljuod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the callback context, `this` tense to callback itself. That's why you are getting the error. You should replace it with,

```js
self.$store.commit('disconnect');
```

where the `self` holds the actual context of Vue. Here is the explanation,

```
methods: {
    async login() {
    var self = this; // You got the context of the method which belongs to Vue

    const auth_res = axios({
      method:'post',
      ...
      }).then(function(res){
        self.$store.commit('disconnect'); // The self.$store is now avaialable in callback
        self.$router.push('/');
      }).catch(function (erreur) {
        ...
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I totally forgot that i was using the self variable.... thanks again.

Comment: Always happy to help. :)